# Deserialize a JSON String into list of lists Java POJO

Tags: java, json, rest, api, serialization

I get below JSON string as a request body for my REST API. I don't like this JSON structure, but I don't have any control on this. It's somebody else posting this message and I have to create a REST API (POST method) and consume this message in my API. So I have to deserialize this into Java objects in my REST controller. It has list of lists objects. I tried several ways with fasterxml, but I was not successful.

```
{
  "messages": [
    [
      {
        "message": "message1_a",
        "info": {
          "timestamp": "2521013204"
        }
      },
      {
        "message": "message1_b",
        "info": [
          {
            "message": "message1_c",
            "info": {
              "id": "asfa-14fs-df"
            }
          },
          {
            "message": "message1_d",
            "info": {
              "reason": "msg_reason",
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Can anybody help me how my Java POJOs should look like?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far, that way we can help you better

Comment: Nobody ever will want to do this. Just for the sake of type safety. But if you insist, take a try on Maps.

Comment: @atmin, if the POJO is programmed in a correct way you should not have any issues with type safety, as long as you dont put the timestamp of one in the same variable as the id of another. As long as you create a POJO which has all the fields with the right type it is a perfectly fine way to parse this data.

Comment: If this is your own code, then I would recommend changing the json structure. I would agree with @atmin, this json does not make sense. Forget Java, just try defining a json schema for this json. It will be a struggle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a array of message.

In Java you can use Spring to transform the Json to a Object.

```
   String url = "http://your/json/url";
   ResponseEntity<Message[]> responseEntity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(url, Message[].class);
```

Be sure that your entity has all the attributes of Json.

The doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html